# How will the dielectric constant of water change when ethyl acetate is added?

Tags: physical-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, ph, solvents

> How will the dielectric constant of water change when ethyl acetate is added?

The $\mathrm{p}K_a$ value of weak acids in aprotic solvents will be lower than in protic solvents because the dielectric constant does not favor ionization. If I increase the $\mathrm{\text{%}}$ concentration of ethyl acetate in water and gradually increase it to nearly $\mathrm{100\text{%}}$ ethyl acetate, how will the $\mathrm{p}K_a$ values of a weak acid in this solvent change?

I want to determine the endpoint with an indicator dye and a suitable titrant of a strong base such as sodium hydroxide. My general aim is to calculate pKa in an easier way.

Comment: Note that AcOEt solubily in water is just 8.3g/100ml https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethyl_acetate what is less than 2% molar fraction.

Comment: ...and note that ethyl acetate will decompose into ethanol and acetic acid in water.